# creating constructors class using 2 other classes as parameters

Tags: c++, class, parameters, constructor

i'm trying to create another class called CorCaixa, that means "ColorBox". It has 2 private attributes:

```
1 Cor object c0("Cor" means Color); <br>
1 ponto object p0("ponto" means point)<br>
```

I don't understand why, when I write the constructor as CaixaCor(ponto p1, Cor c1) the compiler says the following error:

```
C:\Users\Vinicius7\Desktop\Vinicius\CC\CG\Canvas-HSL\src\canvas drawing.cpp||In constructor 'CaixaCor::CaixaCor(ponto, Cor)':|<br>
C:\Users\Vinicius7\Desktop\Vinicius\CC\CG\Canvas-HSL\src\canvas drawing.cpp|140|error: no matching function for call to 'ponto::ponto()'|
```

The other log lines are about the 3 constructors i've declared before.


It seems that the compiler is understanding that i'm trying to create an object of type ponto and not actually saying that this is a constructor that will receive a ponto as a parameter. The same thing happens with the Cor class.

In Stroustrup "The C++ Programing Language" he uses a similar idea  at Chapter 10 pg.242:

```
class Date_and_Time{<br>
private:<br>
    Date d;<br>
    Time t;<br>
public:<br>
    Date_and_Time(Date d, Time t);<br>
    };
```

Why would my example be wrong and his would be right?

```
class Cor{

public:
    Cor();

    Cor(float r, float g, float b){
        this->r = r;
        this->g = g;
        this->b = b;
    }
    inline float  get_r(){
        return this->r;
    }
    inline float get_g(){
        return this->g;
    }
    inline float get_b(){
        return this->b;
    }
    void operator=(const Cor& c1){

        this->r = c1.r;
        this->g = c1.g;
        this->b = c1.b;
    }

private:

    float r;
    float g;
    float b;

};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Cor c1){
    return out <<"("<<c1.get_r()<<","<<c1.get_g()<<","<<c1.get_b()<<")";
}



    class CaixaCor{
public:
    CaixaCor(ponto p1, Cor c1){
        this->p0 = p1;
        this->c0 = c1;
    }
private:
    ponto p0;
    Cor c0;
};
```

Comment: I want to say that you don't have your default constructor implemented. And/or think you should be using pointers.

Comment: What is ponto? It seems it doesn't have a default contructor, the compiler can't find ponto::ponto(). Moreover, you default constructor for Cor is un-defined (not implemented). Hence, the constructor for CaixaCor fails.

Comment: If you change it to `CaixaCor(ponto p1, Cor c1) : p0(p1), c0(c1) {}` it may not need a default constructor.

Comment: ponto is a class for "point" a 2D point in a cartesian coordinate system. That's why the X and Y variables.
If i define a ponto() constructor will this constructor be able to receive an object of that type?

Comment: @WhyCry - Why do you think pointers would be more interesting for this idea? Could you give me an example for that?

Comment: @jensa - Thank you so much, I've maded the changes you stated and It just worked. :D